# number orders for each year and Month

Tags: sql, datepart

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1tj1.jpg)how can i output number orders for each year and Month

I have tried the code but it gives me two columns instead of 4, by each year and month

```
select   month (orderdate), year (orderdate)  ,
   count (orderdate) over (partition by year(orderdate) Order By year(orderdate) desc)  as countoforders
   from sales.SalesOrderHeader
   group by  year (orderdate), month (orderdate),orderdate
```

[sales.SalesOrderHeader.orderdate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut8qg.jpg)[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/950Mh.jpg)

Comment: Pivot table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server

Comment: SQL isn't designed to create a dynamic number of columns. You ***can*** write Dynamic SQL (code that reads data, and writes new SQL code specifically for that data, such as creating a new column for each year/month it finds), but that's generally misuse of SQL. The normalised structure you are currently working with is the correct one for SQL; don't try to force a square peg in to a round hole, it'll just make things worse in the long run. If you need to restructure it for display purposes, do that in your application or reporting layer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using? Give us the structure of your tables and a sample of the output format you want.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: the table is from database adventure works 2019 from the table sales order header    i add the screenshot in my question

Comment: @Golden Lion  yes thank the count by customerid

Comment: create a pivot query using customer_id as the grouping and count the order_ids

Answer (score 1):

Well I found the answer :

```
Select year(o.OrderDate)  as yy , MONTH (o.OrderDate) as MM , count(CustomerID) as count
   from sales.SalesOrderHeader o
   group by year(o.OrderDate), MONTH (o.OrderDate)
   order by yy




Select MM,[2011], [2012], [2013], [2014]
     from (Select year(OrderDate)  as yy , MONTH(OrderDate) as MM , CustomerID
        from sales.SalesOrderHeader) o
        PIVOT(count(CustomerID) for yy in ([2011], [2012], [2013], [2014])) rrr 
         order by MM
```